# Android: How to get a notification when phone gets online

Tags: android

In my application, I need to send some information to a server, but if the phone is offline, I need to wait until the phone get Online and try to send the information again.

I already know how to check if the device has internet connection, my question is, is there any way to be notified (via intent or something) when the status changes from offline to online?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might implement your own service/receiver to check, because in cloud messaging you build a receiver that sends an intent to your activity when it receives some data.